# How do l recover Plesk Cpanel Files

Tags: php, cpanel, plesk

I made a mistake and delete plesk cpanel default files, l need to recover them because right now l cant use SESSIONS

Comment: What kind of default files? Are you able to login using cpanel? Are you able to use file manager in cpanel? Do you have access to WHM? Do you have access to SSH?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this and restore your files. If its cpanel via Plesk, you can go to Website and Domains tab and choose Backup Manager. From there you will choose from your last point of backup and restore. click [this link](https://support.managed.com/kb/a257/how-to-restore-your-site-using-a-backup-created-in-plesk.aspx) for more information